# PHP preg_replace_callback function to mimic handlebars js

Tags: php, regex, function, preg-replace, handlebars.js

So I have this php function that very simply mimics handlebars.js, I have created this so the clients can send out personalised emails from wordpress.

For example:

> Hi **{{name}}**,
>
> Thank you for contacting us.
>
> Kind regards,
>
> **{{author}}**

Would return:

> Hi **John**,
>
> Thank you for contacting us.
>
> Kind regards,
>
> **Sarah**

This function runs before the mail() function. My problem is.. when using these tags on the same line the function gets ignores them

Example:

> Hi **{{firstname}} {{lastname}}**,
>
> Thank you for contacting us.
>
> Kind regards,
>
> **{{author}}**

Would return:

> Hi **{{firstname}} {{lastname}}**,
>
> Thank you for contacting us.
>
> Kind regards,
>
> **Sarah**

Now for my code:

```
    $subject = 'Hello {{name}}, this is an exaple';
    $replace = array(
        '{{name}}' => $name,
        '{{email}}' => $email,
        '{{phone}}' => $phone
    );

    $output = preg_replace_callback('/\{\{(.+)\}\}/', function($match) use ($replace) {
        if(isset($replace[$match[0]])){
            return ($replace[$match[0]]);
        } else {
            return($match[0]);
        } 
    }, $subject);
```

Comment: Use `/U` modifier or `(.+?)` instead of `(.+)`.

Comment: Try this ;) `$output = strtr($subject, $replace);`

Comment: @Zemistr Good point, that would work well too :)

Comment: This worked for me {{{?(#[a-z]+ )?[a-z]+.[a-z]*}?}}

Answer (score 0):

Make your pattern ungreedy by adding a `?` behind `.+`:

```
/\{\{(.+?)\}\}/
```

By default the (greedy) regex grabs everything (as much as it can) till the last occurance which would be in your case

> **{{** firstname}} {{lastname **}}**

because the two curly braces after `lastname` are the last that could be matched in the current line.

Comment: This has worked perfectly thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Why it worked before:

1. The `.` expression matches until a newline unless you use `/s` modifier; if not, you would have seen the effect much sooner,
2. There was only one tag per line; an extension of the above statement but specific to the greedy nature of `.+` and `.*`.

Assuming inside a tag there can't be braces, you can change the memory capture to this:

```
/\{\{([^}]+)\}\}/
     ^^^^^^^
```

It means "match anything that's not a closing curly brace".

Comment: Thank you Jack. I have tested the answer by TiMESPLiNTER and have also tested you answer and they both work perfectly but which is best practice?

Comment: @LeviCole It's generally recommended to use `.+?` only if it's hard to exactly specify what you're matching ... instead of `[^}]` you could also use `\w+` to specify that only letters, digits and underscores may be present in between the curly braces.

Comment: @LeviCole Using `A.*B` or `A.+B` is basically saying "i'm only sure about `A` and `B` ... not sure what goes in between them :)